# android ksoap2 response issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ksoap2

I have an android application that calls a web service various times throughout the application. Since calling the ksoap2 method makes the application not-responsive, I had to put the whole thing into AsyncTask class.

All I did is make a ProgressDialog appear on onPreExecute(), and the call to the web service on doInBackground, as done in my main program. However, although the call to the web service works, the response from the web service is "com.SmartInfinity.InfinityMain$webServiceCall@40697618". FYI com.SmartInfinity is my app package, InfinityMain is my main activity, and webServiceCall is the method that calls the web service.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? The web service is supposed to return results as 
"[field_x1=value_x1;field_y1=value+y1;
field_x2=value_x2;field_y2=value_y2;]"
When I call the same function with the same arguments outside the AsyncTask it works perfectly.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: here is my code:

```
private class webServiceCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> 
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected Object onPostExecute(Object... params) 
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        Object result = null;
        String[] temp = new String[params.length - 2];
        String method_name = params[0];
        String action_name = params[1];
        for (int i = 2; i < params.length; i++)
        {
            temp[i-2] = params[i];
        }
        result = callWebService(method_name, action_name, temp, 60);
        dialog.dismiss();
        return result;
    }

}
```

The result is then converted to a string and used normally. 
Here is how I call the AsyncTask and process my result:

```
Object result = new webServiceCall().execute(UserArgs);


        String str = result.toString();
        String delims = "[=;]+";
        String [] stringuser = str.split(delims);
```

Comment: Looks like a toString that is used faulty if you want the response?

Comment: Actually yes, I do take the response as an object and use .toString(), but that s what I do outside the AsyncTask too, and it works ok. How do I overcome that?

Comment: The toString() must then be called on an empty object (because its run before the response is available?) It would be nice with the relevant code for this issue. Shouldn't be too hard to figure it out :)

Comment: Ok, I added some of my code here. Also for some reason the "OnPostExecute" is highlited from eclipse as never used, but for the moment that is not very important, I set my dialog to disappear in the end of doInBackground.

Answer (score 1):

Object result = new webServiceCall().execute(UserArgs);

That is your problem. The new webServiceCall().execute(UserArgs); doesn't return the result of your asyncTask it only returns an reference to your task. The result of your callWebService is sent to onPostExecute(). It is here you can use the result. Either call a callback from here or you can use the result directly (here you are back in the UI-thread so you can modify the UI here).

Comment: Ok, the result is sent to onPostExecute(), but that is marked by Eclipse as never used locally, I don't get it...

Comment: What happens if you add @Overridde above it? If it works anyway then never mind eclipse, sometimes the eclipse UI bug and warnings doesn't stop you from compiling. Sorry I can't help you more would need the whole project if there's "no" reason for the warning.